Handling Time-Only Strings with IsDate in VB.NET
I'm working with VB.NET and need to handle cases where a date string could represent a full date and time or just a time. Here's my current code snippet:
Dim InvoiceDate As String = Nothing

If IsDate(strInvoiceDate) Then
    InvoiceDate = CDate(strInvoiceDate)
End If

In this code, strInvoiceDate could be a string representing either a full date and time or just a time. If strInvoiceDate represents only a time and does not include a date, I want to set InvoiceDate to an empty string ("").
Here is the implementation of the IsDate function I'm using:
Public Shared Function IsDate(Expression As Object) As Boolean
    If Expression Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If

    If TypeOf Expression Is DateTime Then
        Return True
    End If

    If TypeOf Expression Is String Then
        Dim Result As DateTime = Nothing
        Return Conversions.TryParseDate(CType(Expression, String), Result)
    End If

    Return False
End Function

How can I modify the code to handle cases where strInvoiceDate is only a time and set InvoiceDate to "" in such cases?
Thank you!

Don't use IsDate in the first place. It's a VB6 hold-over that has no place in new VB.NET code. Call Date.TryParseExact and then you can specify exactly what formats are valid. methods like TryParseExact validate and, if possible, convert, so there's no need for the additional CDate.

Also, your code is quite silly as it is. You take a String, convert it to a Date and then assign that to a String variable. That shouldn't even compile because you should have Option Strict On and an implicit narrowing conversion like that should not be allowed. If you need an actual Date then your variable be type Date. If you need a String then you should be calling ToString on your Date and preferably specifying the format, unless you specifically need different formats on different machines with different cultures.

Don't apply tags that are not relevant to your question. Just because a question is about .NET doesn't mean that you can apply the C# tag. You've posted VB code and this question has nothing specifically to do with C#. Don't try to trick people into viewing your question when it's not relevant to them.

I've posted some code for you - but please remove the c# tag.

    Dim strInvoiceDate As String = "2024-07-31"
    Dim invoiceDate As String = Nothing
    Dim outDate As DateTime
    Dim outTime As TimeOnly

    If TimeOnly.TryParse(strInvoiceDate, outTime) Then
        invoiceDate = ""
    ElseIf DateTime.TryParse(strInvoiceDate, outDate) Then
        invoiceDate = outDate.ToString()
    End If


@parangat The TimeOnly structure was first available with .NET 6.

There are several issues with this code I think. The code attempts to parse a string representing a date into either a TimeOnly or DateTime structure.
Incorrect Use of TimeOnly.TryParse: The strInvoiceDate contains only a date, not a time, so using TimeOnly.TryParse will always fail.
Unnecessary String Conversion: If the date parsing succeeds, converting the DateTime back to a string using outDate.ToString() is redundant.
Missing Error Handling: The code doesn't handle cases where the date string cannot be parsed as either a DateTime or TimeOnly.

@Fawlty No, the question states "strInvoiceDate could be a string representing either a full date and time or just a time" so if it is just time the code will set it to Nothing which is desired and if it is a valid DateTime set it to that. Converting the parsed date back to a string could seem redundant but it is what the original code does. It could be useful if the formatting of the DateTime needs to be changed for example. If strInvoiceDate is neither DateTime nor TimeOnly, InvoiceDate is left to whatever value it was before just like the original code.

These pair of functions work together to achieve what you're looking to do. You can adapt them as required to set your own CultureInfo and grow the list of formats to check for. You could consider putting the list of formats to check for into an array, and loop them, with an Exit For if a match is found.
To check if it's time only you need to check if the date returned (when the result is True) is a time only in this way: Dim TimeOnly As Boolean = ReturnedDate.Date = Date.MinValue
''' Change the culture info to suit your own app
Private Shared Function IsValidDateFormat(StringToCheck As String, Format As String, ByRef DateOut As Date) As Boolean
    If StringToCheck.Trim = "" Then Return False
    Dim xDate As Date
    Dim Result As Boolean = Date.TryParseExact(StringToCheck, Format, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, xDate)
    DateOut = xDate
    Return Result
End Function

 ''' <summary>
 ''' Checks a string represents a valid UK date/time
 ''' dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss or dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm or dd/MM/yyyy or HH:mm:ss or HH:mm
 ''' You can alter the code to support the acceptable formats for your app
 ''' </summary>
 ''' <param name="StringToCheck"></param>
 ''' <param name="AllowBlank">Optional - permit empty strings?</param>
 ''' <param name="MinDate">Optional - minimum permitted date</param>
 ''' <param name="MaxDate">Optional - maximum permitted date</param>
 ''' <returns></returns>
 Public Shared Function IsValidDate(StringToCheck As String, Optional ByVal AllowBlank As Boolean = False, Optional ByRef DateOut As Date = Nothing, Optional MinDate As Date = Nothing, Optional MaxDate As Date = Nothing) As Boolean
     If StringToCheck.Trim = "" AndAlso AllowBlank = False Then Return False
     If StringToCheck = "" AndAlso AllowBlank Then Return True
     If MinDate = Nothing Then MinDate = Date.MinValue
     If MaxDate = Nothing Then MaxDate = Date.MaxValue
     Dim xDate As Date
     Dim Result As Boolean = False
     If Result = False Then Result = IsValidDateFormat(StringToCheck,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",xDate)
     If Result = False Then Result = IsValidDateFormat(StringToCheck,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",xDate)
     If Result = False Then Result = IsValidDateFormat(StringToCheck,"dd/MM/yyyy",xDate)
     If Result = False Then Result = IsValidDateFormat(StringToCheck,"HH:mm:ss",xDate)
     If Result = False Then Result = IsValidDateFormat(StringToCheck,"HH:mm",xDate)
     Result = Result And (MinDate = Date.MinValue Or xDate >= MinDate)
     Result = Result And (MaxDate = Date.MaxValue Or xDate <= MaxDate)
     DateOut = xDate
     Return Result
 End Function


You've hardcoded the format in IsValidDateFormat(), shouldn't it use the Format parameter instead?

Yes, I'm an idiot - sorry - that's the problem with writing code in here without testing it.

@SSS I have amended the code. Well spotted.

Just a few ideas to improve that code... You should use Is Nothing to check for being Nothing. However, you can't check for Nothing with a Date, but its default value is DateTime.MinValue anyway - which you might as well have set in the declaration of IsValidDate (and .MaxValue for the other one). Also, you can pass an array of string to DateTime.TryParse for it to check against.

Thank you @AndrewMorton. To anyone reading these comments, I agree with Andrew's suggestions (the array is already mentioned above my code) -  It's always difficult to decide on here how far to take the code (I have work to do!), and I think sometimes it's better to let learners take some foundational code and improve it for themselves. I know my answer has been downvoted by someone, but I stand by it. I find that the use of anything other than TryParseExact inevitably runs you into problems - it is far better to have a comprehensive list of formats that you think your code may encounter.
